# Merge two WordPress installations into one, and keep posts separated?

Tags: database, loop, merging

I have two Wordpress installations that I would like to make into one installation, but still keep the posts (and their meta-data) separated. Both installations currently share the same database.

I would like to be able to loop through both blogs, but each on their own page.

I have extracted both databases using the built in export function in WordPress and am now sitting with two .xml files containing the posts from each database.

Now I would like to import these posts into a new clean WordPress installation, BUT how can I keep the separated? I don't want them to get mixed up, because then I can't show them on their own page.. I am thinking about using a custom loop using WP_Query.

Thanks, I hope you understand what it is I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you choose to import them into the new/merged website, you'll have the option to import the author, or to assign a new one to the imported posts. You could assign different authors to each import and use that to separate the content.

Do both use the same categories? If they don't it should be simple since they will retain the categories when imported.

Comment: Hi, thank you for answering. I didn't think about separating the posts via categories (which they already are, with a few exceptions.) But how can this method be future proofed? If I add a new category I have to make sure it is only shown in either blog A or blog B.

I've been experimenting a little with custom posts. I have made two new post types and then imported one of the blogs. Now I plan to somehow convert these "regular" posts to "custom" posts. And the repeat for the second blog. This way categories wont be a problem, because I can just loop through every custom post of type A or B.

Comment: If you decide to go with the custom_post_type you might want to try this plug-in, or at least take a look at the code to see how to do your own: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/convert-post-types/